# Icon field for Kendo Tree-View

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, treeview

I am using a Kendo Treeview and putting a lot of customization on it which has been working great. I have put some images besides each item and it is working too. So far, I have only been dealing with two properties:

1. dataTextField - To display text
2. dataImageUrlField = To display Image

However, what if I want to use an icon field. what I mean by this is not an image which look like an icon but literally and icon like font-awesome icon with  tag. Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spriteCssClass of the node, i.e.:

```
spriteCssClass = "fa fa-list-alt"
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/use-font-awesome-icons